# After recreating master branch travis does not see commits or branches

Tags: travis-ci

I have rebased my code onto the main branch and squashed changes,
then I renamed the master branch and deleted it. Recreated with the rebased squashed repo.
Now travis does not see any commits any more. 
https://travis-ci.org/stalinizer/opencv

I would not ask on stack overflow but travis points me here, i think it is a bug in the system.

Comment: Now it seems to have taken the branch over night.